# avrdude flash issues

Tags: avrdude, atmega2560, avr-gcc

I want to burn a hex file to a custom ATmega2560 board. I use [this USBasp programmer](https://www.ebay.de/itm/311719627217) for flashing (firmware version 1.01) on my Mac OS X 10.12.6 system. All hex files are compiled with avr-gcc (GCC) 4.9.2.

I use this command to burn fuses (without bootloader):

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega2560 -cusbasp -Pusb -U lfuse:w:0xff:m -U hfuse:w:0xd9:m -U efuse:w:0xfd:m -s -F
```

What is working fine: I can flash smaller (43,266 bytes) programs and they work straight away without bootloader. If I flash **bigger programs (99,986 bytes)** they do not run. I can verify if the program runs because they spit out data via TTL. The smaller program does work but the bigger one does not produce anything.

I turned on "Code verify" and I can see for smaller programs:

```
avrdude: 43264 bytes of flash verified
```

big programs:

```
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0001
         0x90 != 0x94
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
```

**Any hints on this side?**

Secondly: after deleting the whole flash, when I flash a custom bootloader (from Atmel Studio - fuses are Ext. 0xFD, High: 0xD2, Low: 0xFF), command:

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega2560 -cusbasp -Pusb -U flash:w:ATmega_Example.hex:i
```

and afterwards read the flash, the bootloader ended up in several blocks within the flash.

From the readout hexfile (data blocks):

Line 1

```
>:20000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00
```

All the flash is 0xFF until Line 1921

> :20F0000077C000009BC0000099C0000097C0000095C0000093C0000091C000008FC0000066

Some more data until Line 1995.

> :20F940000895F894FFCF65300000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF31

All the flash is 0xFF until Line 3970.

> :20F0000077C000009BC0000099C0000097C0000095C0000093C0000091C000008FC0000066

Some more data until Line 4044.

> :20F940000895F894FFCF65300000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF31

And so on... I can find similar data 4 times in the file.

**Is this a problem with the flashing or with reading the data from the chip?**

Let me know if you need more information to help me here.

Comment: any change if using -D flag?

Comment: no change when I flash with the "-D" option

Comment: Define "smaller" and "bigger" wrt the code size.

Comment: small: 43.266 bytes
big: 99.986 bytes

Comment: I added verification information. On bigger problems it fails:
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0001
         0x90 != 0x94
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

Comment: Could the size limit be 65,536 bytes? IIRC, there was an issue with addresses longer that 16 bits requiring a special extension of the normal upload protocol. But I don't remember whether the size limit was 2^16 bytes or 2^16 16-bit words.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use [AVRDUDESS](https://github.com/zkemble/AVRDUDESS?files=1) for uploading sketch on atmega328p and attiny85. Try to use it and run detect.
I answer this because AVRDUDESS is very easy to use and it can help you to show more info of your error.
I think you maybe have a bad wiring or a defect cable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that it's going to fix your problem, but few years ago I had similar issue. I was trying to upload program to ATTiny13A using cheap e-bay USPasp and got verification errors. One step of my solution was changing programmer id from "`-c usbasp`" to "`-c usbasp-clone`"

More here: https://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_4.html

[image: USBasp vs USBasp-clone]

Answer (score 1):

I am familiar with that issue. I don't have an USBasp but an USBtinyISP but I think the problem is the same.

The USBtinyISP cannot read or write past 64kiB. Since AVR are 8-bit machines with 16-bit addressing they cannot address past 64kiB on their own. A special addressing schema is used on runtime and also during flash. (I think it was larger page sizes during flash.)

I could manage to get around the issue by using an original [Atmel AVRISP mkII](https://www.microchip.com/developmenttools/ProductDetails/PartNo/atavrisp2).